# Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded - hex is different

Tags: node.js, angular, asp-classic, buffer

I have a legacy classic asp application, that allows us to upload pdf files. The file is saved as hex into a MS SQL DB into an image column. Here is a snip of the data in the column:

```
0x4A564245526930784C6A634E436957317462573144516F784944416762324A7144516F...
```

We are now working on a rework of the app using node.js as our backend and angular4 as the front end. As part of that, we need to be able to download the same file in the new app. If I upload the same file using angular4 then the image data looks like this:

```
0x255044462D312E370D0A25B5B5B5B50D0A312030206F626A0D0A3C3C2F547970652F43...
```

As you can see the hex is completely different and I am not sure what is causing this. I have tried to look at the classic asp code, but its very old and there is no special encoding or such that is happening that would cause this.

In Angular4 we are using the standard input type file control with the `change` event to capture the contents of the file and then saving it into our db:

```
myReader.onloadend = (f) => {
      let image64;
      if (myReader.result.toString()) {
        let base64id = ';base64,';
        image64 = myReader.result.substr(myReader.result.indexOf(base64id) + base64id.length);
      }
      someService.upload(image64);
    }
```

So nothing crazy going on, right?  The problem now is that I am able to download the file uploaded via angular fine, but not the ones that were uploaded via classic asp. I receive the following error when I try:

> Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not
>   correctly encoded.

Here is the code used to upload the files via classic ASP:

```
Public Function Load()
    Dim PosBeg, PosEnd, PosFile, PosBound, boundary, boundaryPos, Pos
        Dim Name, Value, FileName, ContentType
        Dim UploadControl

        PosBeg = 1
        PosEnd = InstrB(PosBeg,m_FormRawData,getByteString(chr(13)))
        boundary = MidB(m_FormRawData,PosBeg,PosEnd-PosBeg)
        boundaryPos = InstrB(1,m_FormRawData,boundary)
        'Get all data inside the boundaries
        Do until (boundaryPos=InstrB(m_FormRawData,boundary & getByteString("--")))
      Set UploadControl = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

            Pos = InstrB(BoundaryPos,m_FormRawData,getByteString("Content-Disposition"))
            Pos = InstrB(Pos,m_FormRawData,getByteString("name="))
            PosBeg = Pos+6
            PosEnd = InstrB(PosBeg,m_FormRawData,getByteString(chr(34)))
            Name = getString(MidB(m_FormRawData,PosBeg,PosEnd-PosBeg))
            PosFile = InstrB(BoundaryPos,m_FormRawData,getByteString("filename="))
            PosBound = InstrB(PosEnd,m_FormRawData,boundary)

            If  PosFile<>0 AND (PosFile<PosBound) Then
                PosBeg = PosFile + 10
                PosEnd =  InstrB(PosBeg,m_FormRawData,getByteString(chr(34)))
                FileName = getString(MidB(m_FormRawData,PosBeg,PosEnd-PosBeg))

                UploadControl.Add "FileName", FileName
                Pos = InstrB(PosEnd,m_FormRawData,getByteString("Content-Type:"))
                PosBeg = Pos+14
                PosEnd = InstrB(PosBeg,m_FormRawData,getByteString(chr(13)))

                ContentType = getString(MidB(m_FormRawData,PosBeg,PosEnd-PosBeg))
                UploadControl.Add "ContentType",ContentType

                PosBeg = PosEnd+4
                PosEnd = InstrB(PosBeg,m_FormRawData,boundary)-2
                Value = MidB(m_FormRawData,PosBeg,PosEnd-PosBeg)

                UploadControl.Add "value" , Value

                m_dicFileData.Add LCase(name), UploadControl
            Else
                Pos = InstrB(Pos,m_FormRawData,getByteString(chr(13)))
                PosBeg = Pos+4
                PosEnd = InstrB(PosBeg,m_FormRawData,boundary)-2
                Value = getString(MidB(m_FormRawData,PosBeg,PosEnd-PosBeg))

                UploadControl.Add "value" , Value   
            End If

            m_dicForm.Add LCase(name), UploadControl

            BoundaryPos=InstrB(BoundaryPos+LenB(boundary),m_FormRawData,boundary)
        Loop

        Load = m_blnSucceed
    End Function
```

Any idea what I can do here to fix this? I need to be able to download the old files as well. Is there an encoding or something else I am missing here?

After further looking into this, it seems the following is causing the error: Node.js will send a buffer to the front-end. On the front-end I then convert the buffer into base64 using the below code:

```
  _arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    let base64 = '';
    let bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    let len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      bbase64 += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return base64;
  }
```

The returned base64 from the old classic asp is returned as garbage and looks like this:

> *R{£ÌõGpÃì@j¾é>i¿ê  A l  Ä ð!!H!u!¡!Î!û"'"U""¯"Ý#
>   (?(q(¢(Ô))8)k))Ð**5*h**Ï++6+i++Ñ,,9,n,¢,×-''I'z'«'Ü(
>   3F33¸3ñ4+4e44Ø55M55Â5ý676r6®6é7$7`77×88P88È99B99¼9ù:6:t

I am still not sure how to fix this though.

Comment: There is no way anyone can help you without seeing the Classic ASP code. Of course it's old, that totally not relevant. There's nothing built-in ASP that converts file to Hex, you must be using some special library or code, so we should try and reverse engineer that code and understand how it's working.

Comment: @ShadowWizard fair. I have edited my request to show the asp code.

Comment: Does your classic ASP app have any way to open or process the files that were uploaded via itself?